# OPTIONS Cors method cannot be prevented

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, cors

In system.config file I removed the OPTIONS method declaration and I'm waiting that requests which's method type is OPTIONS must be prevented. If I remove other method types from system.config file, requests having them is prevented but my controll not working for OPTIONS method type.

system.config file;

```
 CORS_ALLOW_GENERIC_HTTP_REQUESTS=true
 CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN="*"
 CORS_SUPPORTED_METHODS=" HEAD, PUT,POST, GET, DELETE"
 CORS_SUPPORTED_HEADERS="*"
```

My doOptions method;

```
protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  corsRequestHandler.tagRequest(request);
  CORSRequestType type = CORSRequestType.detect(request);
  if (type.equals(CORSRequestType.PREFLIGHT)) {
     try {
        corsRequestHandler.handlePreflightRequest(request, response);
     }
     catch (InvalidCORSRequestException e) {
        logger.error("Invalid CORS Request Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     }
     catch (CORSOriginDeniedException e) {
        logger.error("CORS Origin Denied Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     }
     catch (UnsupportedHTTPMethodException e) {
        logger.error("Unsupported HTTP Method Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     }
     catch (UnsupportedHTTPHeaderException e) {
        logger.error("Unsupported HTTP Header Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     }
  }
}
```

I am out of ideas, please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of OPTIONS ıs a Preflighted request, it can not prevented. Unlike simple requests , "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send.

For more information , visit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)